# Layout bounds not showing in Fultter app but it shows for other apps

Tags: android, flutter, android-developer-api

I just started with flutter and created a blank app with default config, when I turned on show layouts bounds from developer options it is not showing any boundaries like any other app.

How is this happening?

Comment: Have a look at [Flutter visual debugging](https://flutter.io/docs/testing/debugging#visual-debugging) and [Flutter widget inspector](https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/inspector#getting-started-with-the-inspector).

Comment: In flutter everything is a Widgets. Widget rendering is handled by the ObjectRender in flutter. You can’t get the size or location on the screen of a widget, because a widget is like a blueprint, it’s not actually on the screen. It’s only a description of what variables the underlying render object should use.

Comment: @FirzanShaikh Could you please explain how flutter renders layout that the android layout boundary doesn't recognize any layout?

Answer (score 37):

To show **layouts bounds** from developer options for Flutter apps, we have to do this

1. import this package in `main.dart` class.

   ```
   import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
   ```
2. in `build()` or `main()` you have to set this `debugPaintSizeEnabled` variable as `true`.

   ```
   debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
   ```

**Example**: Here is my complete class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main()
{
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(    
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
    home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Perfect. It saved my lots of time. Thank You.